# How can I access a private (non-static) method in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, friend

Currently I am working on a project where I want to control a model train for a nice showcase.

I have multiple locomotives which all have a unique address (just think of it as a UUID). Some locomotives have a headlight, some of them have a flashing light, some have both and some of them have none.

My base class is this:

```
class GenericLocomotive : public Nameable, public Describable {

private:
    uint16_t address;

public:
    GenericLocomotive(const char* name, const char* description, uint16_t address);
    void setFunction(uint8_t command, bool val);
```

Now I want to have a different class which provides the functionality to enable and disable the headlight:

```
class HasHeadLight {

public:
    void activateHeadlight();
    void deactivateHeadlight();
}
```

My goal is to have a specific class for every locomotive (with different functionality) which looks something like this:

```
class <SpecificLocomotive> : public GenericLocomotive, public HasHeadlight, public HasFlashlight,... {
    ...
}
```

The problem is, that I must have access to the private field 'address' of my GenericLocomotive class and I also have to call the function setFunction(...) from my HasHeadlight class.

I am quite new to C++ and just found out about the concept of friend classes and methods, but I can not quite get it to work, because even with the declaration of the method setFunction(...) as a friend, I can not just call something like

```
this->setFunction(HEADLIGHT_COMMAND, true);
```

from my HasHeadlight-class, because the function is not declared in 'this'.

How can I access the method from my other class? Is this friend thing even needed or is there a completely different way to structure my C++ program?

Comment: The problem isn't actually about C++, but rather about inheritance. `HasHeadlight` doesn't inherit from `GenericLocomotive` and thus won't be able to access any of its member variables and methods. `friend` classes won't help here either, if you don't instantiate an object within that particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood how [class inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/inheritance) works:

> Inheritance establishes an is-a relationship between a parent and a child. The is-a relationship is typically stated as as a specialization relationship, i.e., child is-a parent.

There are many ways you can tackle what you want to achieve here, but this is not it. You're on the right track as far as treating the different train components as separate objects, and one way to achieve that would be to instead make each component a member of the specialized locomotive:

```
class HeadLight {
public:
    void activateHeadlight();
    void deactivateHeadlight();
}

class SpecialLocomotive : public GenericLocomotive {
    HeadLight mHeadlight;
    Flashlight mFlashlight;

public:
    SpecialLocomotive(const char* name, const char* description, uint16_t address)
    :    GenericLocomotive(name, description, address) {
        setFunction(HEADLIGHT_COMMAND, true);
    }

    void toggleLight(bool on) {
        if (on) {
            mHeadlight.activateHeadlight();
        } else {
            mHeadlight.void deactivateHeadlight();
        }
    }
    /* so on and so forth /*
}
```

There's not enough details to go further with it. If you need to call `setFunction` from within `Headlight`, I would consider that a poor design choice, but there are other ways.

Comment: okay, I  get the point here. But how could I structure my program to also support locomotives with only one of these features? Would I then use two subclasses of GenericLocomotive which I then further inherit?

Comment: You /could/ do that, but I wouldn't advise it. At that point, you run afoul of the diamond problem where your subclasses have the same parent class which is initialized twice and causes ambiguity. In that case, you could use the virtual keyword in subclasses to mitigate the issue. I would just create two different Locomotive classes with their respective members. If all types of Locomotives are hardcoded this would be optimal.

Comment: If you are worried about code duplication, I would suggest researching template classes and go that route.